# A regex for removing certain characters only if there is a space character on either side

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a Javascript string:

```
var myString= "word = another : more new: one = two";
```

I am trying to figure out a regex that would produce this:

```
var myString= "word another more new: one two";
```

So when the pattern of a space followed by a = sign then followed by another space would result in the = sign being removed.

Likewise for the : character as well.

If the = character or the : character are removed that is fine or if those characters are replaced by a space character that is fine as well.

In summary to replace multiple occurrences of an = or a : if and only if they
surrounded by a space character.

Whichever regex is easier to write.

Comment: `yourstring.replace(/ [=:] /g, ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    //save the appropriate RegEx in the variable re
//It looks for a space followed by either a colon or equals sign
// followed by another space
    let re = /(\s(=|:)\s)/g;

//load test string into variable string
    let string = "word = another : more new: one = two";
//parse the string and replace any matches with a space
    let parsed_string = string.replace(re, " ");

//show result in the DOM
    document.body.textContent = string + " => " + parsed_string;
```

Comment: Note that using a character class `[=:]` is _much_ more efficient than alternation within a capturing group `(=|:)` — and enclosing the whole thing in another capturing group `/( ... )/g` just add overhead that you don't need because you're not doing anything with the captures ... also `\s` is _any_ whitespace, not just spaces, but that change may be more desirable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not with javascript... but you get the idea:

```
echo "word = another : more new: one = two" | sed 's/ [:=] / /g'
```

returns the desired string:

```
word another more new: one two
```

Explanation: the expression `/ [:=] /` finds all "space followed by either colon or equals sign followed by space" and replaces with "space".